# Get all unique values in an array (remove duplicates) fot nest array / object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, unique

i know there has many answer for unique array

but they can't handle with array of array

---

what i want is

source array

```
[
    1,
    0,
    true,
    undefined,
    null,
    false,
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    { a: { b: 2 } },
    { a: { b: 2 } },
    { a: { b: 3 } },
    { a: { b: undefined } },
    { a: {  } },
    { a: { b: 3, c: undefined } },
]
```

the return

```
[
    1,
    0,
    true,
    undefined,
    null,
    false,
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'c', 'b'],
    { a: { b: 2 } },
    { a: { b: 3 } },
    { a: { b: undefined } },
    { a: {  } },
    { a: { b: 3, c: undefined } },
]
```

- [arr-unique](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arr-unique) can handle object[], but can't handle array of array
- Set can't too

---

fail code

```
console.log(array_unique(data));

console.log([...new Set(data)]);

console.log(data.filter(function (el, index, arr)
{
    return index == arr.indexOf(el);
}));
```

===================

**update**

i create a module for this [array-hyper-unique](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-hyper-unique), but didn't use json stringify because it has a bug when valuse is regexp

Comment: is `['a', 'b', 'c']` the same with `['a', 'c', 'b']`?

Comment: @Eddie not same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One easy method would be to `stringify` the arrays and objects in order to identify duplicates:

```js
const input = [
    1,
    true,
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    { a: { b: 2 } },
    { a: { b: 2 } },
    { a: { b: 3 } },
    { a: { b: 3, c: undefined } },
];

const outputSet = new Set();
const stringifiedObjs = new Set();
input.forEach(item => {
  if (typeof item !== 'object') outputSet.add(item);
  else {
    // replace undefineds with something, else they'll be ignored by JSON.stringify:
    const stringified = JSON.stringify(
      item,
      (k, v) => v === undefined ? 'undefined-value' : v
    );
    if (!stringifiedObjs.has(stringified)) {
      outputSet.add(item);
      stringifiedObjs.add(stringified)
    }
  }
});
console.log([...outputSet]);
```

Comment: It works for me with `undefined` dupes and `{ a: { b: undefined } },` dupes, what were you thinking of?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: { b: undefined } })); // {"a":{}}` the `b` property is missing.

Comment: looks like this is best answer now

Answer (score 3):

Try by converting elements to string using `JSON.stringify` and use `indexOf` to push these elements to another array,only if the another array does not contain this element. Then again use `map` & `JSON.parse` to convert string to the original format

```js
var data = [
  1,
  true, ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  {
    a: {
      b: 2
    }
  },
  {
    a: {
      b: 2
    }
  },
  {
    a: {
      b: 3
    }
  },
]
// Create a new array of only string 
// map will give new array and JSON.stringify will convert elements to string
var newData = data.map(function(item) {
  return JSON.stringify(item)
})
//An empty array which will contain only unique values
var uniques = [];
// loop over the array of stirngs and check
//if that value is present in uniques array
//if not then push the element
newData.forEach(function(item) {
  if (uniques.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    uniques.push(item)
  }
});
//Convert array of string to json
var parsedArr = uniques.map(function(item) {
  return JSON.parse(item)
});
console.log(parsedArr)
```

Comment: @NinaScholz he modified the original array and later on added the undefined property

Answer (score 2):

The reason you method does not work, is because the first `['a', 'b', 'c']`, and the second `['a', 'b', 'c']` are *different objects*, as are the first and second instances of `{ a: { b: 2 } }`.

Because of this, even though you add them to `Set`, they will be considered non-equivalent to each other, and therefore, not be filtered for uniqueness.

It seems you want to get a unique array based on the absolute values in each object. One easy way to do this is to use the ES6 `Map` like so:

```
function uniq(arr) {
  var uniqMap = new Map()
  arr.forEach(element => {
    uniqMap.set(JSON.stringify(element), element)
  })
  return [...uniqMap.values()]
}
```

You can then get the result you are looking for:

```
uniq(data)
//Result: [ 1, true, [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], { a: { b: 2 } }, { a: { b: 3 } } ]
```

Comment: looks like ur answer is best near if there has no unknow bug

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach for objects and check the values.

```js
function check(a, b) {
    if (!a || typeof a !== 'object') {
        return a === b;
    }

    var keys = Object.keys(a);
    return keys.length === Object.keys(b).length
        && keys.every(k => k in b && check(a[k], b[k]));
}

var array = [1, 0, true, undefined, null, false, ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'b'], { a: { b: 2 } }, { a: { b: 2 } }, { a: { b: 3 } }, { a: { b: undefined } }, { a: {} }, { a: { b: 3, c: undefined } }],
    unique = array.reduce((r, b) => (r.some(a => check(a, b)) || r.push(b), r), []);
  
console.log(unique);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```